# SATO Label Printer - Inconsistency Between Printers

Tags: printing, reporting-services, fonts, barcode-printing

We use SATO CL412e printers to print labels (3x7), with the label coming from a local SSRS report.  Until recently, this setup worked without issue.  A few months ago we modified the label, and implemented (new implementation) at one site (Site A).  Then a few weeks ago, we pushed the change out to another site (Site B) that had previously been using this label (old version).  Since we did this, the label at Site B is... weird.

The barcode is quite clearly not right, and all the normal characters are squished together, and perhaps bolded.  Theoretically, we have proved that it is not the application (which recently changed as well) or the label report because it works fine at Site A, as well as from a different printer (same model, same drivers, etc.) at Site B.

Yesterday the drivers at Site B were updated to match Site A, which resulted in no change.  This morning we found a few settings in the web interface that were different.  I have not heard yet, but I seriously doubt it will have an effect.

What am I missing?  To date, this exactly configuration works on three printers, and fails on one.  I am at a complete loss as to what to check next.  What could possibly cause this behavior?

Edit:

It has been discovered that this happens only through RDP.  When we use a Citrix connection to the same server, we have no problem.  It has been suggested that maybe this is a problem with the Internet Explorer settings.  Any basis to this, and what settings?

Answer (score 0):

RDP has a feature which connects your local printers to the remote server. This can mean the printer you get when connected with RDP is different than the printer when you are locally working on that server, or using Citrix. It's possible your local workstation has the same printer defined with different settings.
In your RDP connection dialog, click "Settings" and click the "Local resources" tab. Then clear the "Printers" checkbox to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Right, but in this case the RDP was a thin client, so there were no local printers.