# RDP - Incorrect Printer Driver

Tags: printing, rdp, thin-client

I recently [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535347/sato-label-printer-inconsistency-between-printers) about a printer issue.  We have narrowed it down to happening only when using RDP from a Windows 7 computer or newer thin client.

Basically, whenever we RDP from Win7 or a thin client (I say newer, but we have only tested on one), we seem to be getting the wrong print driver for our SATO printer.  I tried searching around to find out how RDP decides what driver/settings to use, but have not had much luck.

We have tried the following scenarios:

- Print directly from XP: works
- Print directly from Win7: works
- Print through Citrix from XP: works
- Print through Citrix from Win7: works
- Print through Citrix on thin client: works
- Print through RDP from XP: works
- Print through RDP from Win7: fails
- Print through RDP from thin client: fails
- Print through Citrix from thin client (Same one): works

What could cause this behavior, and how do I fix it?  Not using RDP is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a resolution issue.  I do not fully understand it, but I am told it is a known issue with SSRS (even with local reports, apparently).  I am able to reliably repro and correct by changing resolutions.  4:3 and 5:4 both work.  Everything else apparently does not.